# IR sensor program will not run

Tags: gpio, python-3

When I run it nothing happens either in command prompt or the shell. I think I am missing some code line but I got it from a online project and cant ferret out the problem

This code is supposed to test 2x IR sensors I have hooked up via breadboard

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN)                            #Right sensor connection
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Left sensor connection
while True:
 i=GPIO.input(3)                         #Reading output of right IR sensor
 j=GPIO.input(16)                        #Reading output of left IR sensor
if i==0:                                #Right IR sensor detects an object
 print("Obstacle detected on Left"),i
time.sleep(0.1)
if j==0:                              #Left IR sensor detects an object
 print("Obstacle detected on Right"),j
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: This is a basic Python error, nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.  Perhaps search for a Python tutorial.  You must have incorrectly copied the code.  Unlike a lot of programming languages white space is important to Python.

Comment: I would ask this at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Something to consider for future coding: per [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) *Use 4 spaces per indentation level.*

Comment: You will find this much easier with gpiozero's `MotionSensor` https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#motion-sensor-d-sun-pir

Answer (score 0):

The indentation seems to be wrong.  Try this instead:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN)                            #Right sensor connection
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Left sensor connection
while True:
  i=GPIO.input(3)                         #Reading output of right IR sensor
  j=GPIO.input(16)                        #Reading output of left IR sensor
  if i==0:                                #Right IR sensor detects an object
    print("Obstacle detected on Left"),i
  time.sleep(0.1)
  if j==0:                              #Left IR sensor detects an object
    print("Obstacle detected on Right"),j
  time.sleep(0.1)
```